# How to change vendor\magento\module-eav\etc\db_schema.xml column type?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5

I recently upgrade magento **2.3.3 to 2.3.5** and I had a error while running : `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Image Of Error : [error](https://prnt.sc/1620alm)

I follow to : **vendor\magento\module-eav\etc\db_schema.xml** and I see that on tables : `eav_entity_attribute & eav_attribute_group` there is column **"attribute_group_id"** with type of : **"smallint"** and its need to Be **INT**.

Can anyone please tell me how do I override this **vendor\magento\module-eav\etc\db_schema.xml** file and change the column to INT please >? Ty

Comment: can you please share the actual error here if it is related to core most probably quality patch will be available

Comment: i did share the error  : https://prnt.sc/1620alm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try to override the column type by creating a custom module.**

1. Create module.
2. Create db_schema.xml in your namespace/module/etc and add following code.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
>     <table name="tablename" resource="default" >
> <column xsi:type="int" name="eav_attribute_group" nullable="true" length="11" comment="eav attribute group "/>
>     </table>
> </schema>
> ```

3. Add module dependency in your namespace/module/etc/module.xml

> ```
> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
> xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
>     <module name="{VendorName_ModuleName}">
>         <sequence>
>             <module name="Magento_Eav"/>
>         </sequence>
>     </module>
> </config>
> ```

Comment: ty Very Much My Friend Its Work Perfectly : )

Comment: accept answer as soultion will be apricaiated.